# awk to get all request headers with new lines

Tags: curl, awk

i`m using curl to get request headers by using following command

```
curl -v -fsSL example.com 2>&1 1>/dev/null | grep -E "^(<|>|curl: )" | sed 's/< //' | sed 's/> //'
```

and the output would be as following

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com
User-Agent: curl/7.68.0
Accept: */*

HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Location: http://www.example.com/
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date: Fri, 28 May 2021 15:39:57 GMT
Expires: Sun, 27 Jun 2021 15:39:57 GMT
Cache-Control: public, max-age=2592000
Server: gws
Content-Length: 219
X-XSS-Protection: 0
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN

GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: www.example.com
User-Agent: curl/7.68.0
Accept: */*

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 28 May 2021 15:39:57 GMT
Expires: -1
Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
X-XSS-Protection: 0
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Set-Cookie: aaaa
Accept-Ranges: none
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

all i need ti filter out only request headers starting from GET as following

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com
User-Agent: curl/7.68.0
Accept: */*
```

so i tried `awk 'BEGIN{RS=ORS="\n\n";FS=OFS="\n\n"}/GET/'`
but it print the whole thing

Comment: "_by using following command_" - that's a flurry of "commands"

Comment: @TedLyngmo i know it's a bit messy but i`m trying to get it done as much as i know, if you can help i would be thankful

Comment: What you can do is to break every command down until you don't understand the response - and then ask a question about that.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide concise, testable sample input (ie. the output of `curl`, not the output of some chain of commands you run **after** calling `curl`) and the expected output given that input so we can help you.

Answer (score 1):

You can get rid of all the pipeline commands and use a single `awk` to get your output:

```sh
curl -v -fsSL 'https://google.in' 2>&1 |
awk '{gsub(/^[<>][[:space:]]*/, "")} $1 == "GET" {p=1; fn="out." ++n} !NF {close(fn); p=0} p {print > fn}'

cat out.1
GET / HTTP/2
Host: google.in
User-Agent: curl/7.64.1
Accept: */*

cat out.2
GET / HTTP/2
Host: www.google.co.in
User-Agent: curl/7.64.1
Accept: */*
```

Comment: really thank you so mush it get done but what you suggest if i need to put each request in separate text file for later debugging!

Comment: but this will combine the whole output in one file, what i mean each request in separate file

Comment: working like charm, thanks i tried to specialize a directory by using ```curl -v -fsSL 'https://google.in' 2>&1 | awk '{gsub(/^[<>][[:space:]]*/, "")} $1 == "GET" {p=1; fn="dir/out." ++n} !NF {close(fn); p=0} p {print > fn}'``` but it miss the whole thing maybe i could cd into dir before running thing command.

Comment: yup it worked and now i am trying combine the whole thing in loop against different domains by using ```while read line ; do curl -v -fsSL $line 2>&1 | awk -v var='$line' '{gsub(/^[<>][[:space:]]*/, "")} $1 == "GET" {p=1; fn="var/out." ++n} !NF {close(fn); p=0} p {print > fn}' ; done < all_domains.txt``` but looks even if i defined the variable inside awk but it dosn`t recognize it and error redirection came out

Comment: ```awk: cmd. line:1: (FILENAME=- FNR=5) fatal: can't redirect to `google.com/out.1' (No such file or directory)
awk: cmd. line:1: (FILENAME=- FNR=5) fatal: can't redirect to `www.google.com/out.1' (No such file or directory)```

Comment: Please avoid extended discussion and as I have already provided a solution to your original problem. For this problem you are getting error because `google.com` is not a directory. You should better use: `fn=var "-out."`